# gnuplot on Linux draws small ugly dots at data points

Tags: gnuplot

I have gnuplot 4.6 on Linux as well as gnuplot 4.7 on Windows at my disposal. When I use the Windows version, I get a beautiful diagram. However, the Linux version draws a small dot at very data point. That looks very ugly. Of course, I use exactly the same .plt file to render both diagrams. How can I stop the Linux version from drawing that small dots?

[image]

The script used is:

```
set terminal pdfcairo
set output "foo.pdf"
plot 'bar.dat' with linespoints pointtype 4
```

Comment: Can you post an example script?  That will help others answer the question.  I'm curious to see how to resolve this myself; the same thing has been pestering me when I use the postscript terminal under linux.

Comment: The following three commands are enough: set terminal pdfcairo # set output "foo.pdf" # plot 'bar.dat'with linespoints pointtype 4

Comment: @user1494080 -- I used `pdfcairo` with the plot command `plot sin(x) w lp pt 4` and I was not able to reproduce this on Ubuntu linux.  It is possible that it has to do with the version of the cairo library used on the back-end.

Comment: I think my cairo version is `1.8.10` (which I was able to obtain from the `cairo-version.h` header file)

Comment: I tried several versions of libcairo2, including the most recent one, but the small dots were always still there. Btw, the Linux system is an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64.

Comment: two things to try, 1 transfer your linux pdf to the windows system and look at it with the same viewer, see if the dots persist. 2 run terminal tests in gnuplot on both systems. You might find that the dotless symbols are numbered differently by the different drivers or some such.

Comment: @andyras the postscript driver most definately has dotted and dotless symbols available by specifying appropriate point type. simply  run 'test' (instead of any 'plot' command ) to see all available symbols.